# Python subplot and image size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

What I am doing wrong to get the two figures side by side and *both* 10x10?
One on top of the other would also be okay.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)#    subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(20, 25)
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdGy', edgecolor='none')
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, 40, cmap='RdGy')
ax2.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))`?

Comment: Then the right image is a square, which will be correct, but it is still over the first image. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Red-Cloud : Does my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(20, 25)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdGy', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 40, cmap='RdGy')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also plot both in single plot, refer below code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(20, 25)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='autumn_r', lw=0.5,edgecolor='black', rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

[image]

If a add transparency to the surface facets then I can see the contours, but it looks really cluttered (see code and image below)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(45, 35)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='autumn_r', lw=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.5)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, colors="b", linestyles="solid")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. My `projection='3d'` was set too early